# Calculo de probabilidad en R

Tags: r

estoy haciendo un trabajo en R y me piden lo siguiente...

En una mesa de dados de un casino se echa un par de dados no trucados 180 veces por hora.

En 24 horas se tiran los dados 4320.

Los parámetros de la distribución que me dan son (4320, 1/6)

Calcular con ayuda de R la probabilidad de que haya entre 700 y 750  sumas de 7 en 24 horas.

¿Cómo puede calcular esta probabilidad en R?

En papel puedo hacerla pero en R como se hace?

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Puedes compartirlo?

Comment: Bueno a mano en papel si que lo hice,usando el teorema central del limite saque la probabilidad que me piden pero con R no se como calcularlo.

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola!

Te sugiero los siguientes pasos:

**1)** **¿De qué distribución estamos hablando?** Aquí para calcular uno de los parámetros posiblemente tendrás que echar cuentas.

**2)** Una vez sepas la distribución, la familia de funciones **r**norm, **d**norm, **p**norm, . . . (no necesariamente con la distribución normal) te ayudarán a calcular el valor que te piden.

Lo importante es que definas bien el primer paso para poder ayudarte con el segundo. Espero tu respuesta.

Saludos,